# python Список изменяется хотя с ним не производится операций

Tags: python, list

У меня есть рекурсивная функция, вот маленький кусочек из её работы:

```
k = list(visited[:].copy())

if count == 2:
    for i in visited:
        print(i)
    print(id(visited),5)
    print(id(k),6)
        
rec(id_,x-1,y,count+1,k, path.copy(), wallsV, wallsH,w,h)
        
if count == 2:
    print(id(visited),7)
    for i in visited:
        print(i)
```

Создаётся копия массива `visited` в переменную `k`, далее `k` передаётся в следущую итерацию рекурсии

В подтверждение того что это новый список а не ссылка выводятся `id` списков, в выводах с пометками 5 и 7 они одинаковые, а с пометкой 6 другой `id`

И всё бы хорошо но `visited` по итогу изменяется, что видно на выводе:

```
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
2030876399296 5
2030876399680 6
2030876399296 7
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

`visited` изменяется хотя с ним вообще не происходит никаких действий! Объясните пожалуйста почему так. Я проверил на нескольких версиях питона и на онлайн интерпретаторе, результат одинаковый

Comment: Матвей, перенес ваш ответ из комментариев в ответы. В дальнейшем так действуйте, если сами отвечаете на свой вопрос, чтобы все могли видет ответ в базе знаний. В конце длинного вопроса его мало кто найдет.

Comment: Причём, непонятно, где вы с этим списком вообще работаете. В функции rec, явно его туда не передавая? Это плохой стиль - по приведённому фрагменту кода нет никаких обращений к списку visited между печатями его id.

Comment: Кстати, `[:]` тоже делает копию списка. Так что вы зачем-то два раза подряд копируете список, но при этом обе копии "мелкие".

Comment: @CrazyElf В этом и была проблема, я не мог понять, почему список изменяется хотя я к нему никак не обращаюсь, а оба метода копирования использовал что бы показать что они оба не работают в данном случае

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ автора вопроса (перенесен): "проблема оказалась в том что ссылку на основной список я убрал, а вложенные списки так и остались слинкованы. Нужно было использовать `copy.deepcopy`".